# Jvisualvm main window of running jvm's no longer appears

Tags: jvisualvm

Somehow I have managed to squash the  main window of `Jvisualvm`: it is not longer coming up with the list of running jvm's. How can this be reset?

[image]

I have tried killing and restarting a few times now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After snooping around the os/x filesystem I found it here:

~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualVM/8u40/config/Windows2Local/

So the following cleaned it up:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualVM/8u40/config/Windows2Local/
```